# Save integer into vector after foor loop with conditionals

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, vector

I have to set up a for loop that differences between odd and even numbers. I'm thinking to use an if/else statement into the for loop that evaluates de residue to know if is even or odd. Once done it, i'd like to save the number in a vector: one vector for the if condition, and another for the else.

This is my code!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays; 
import java.util.*;
  
class Even_odd_array { 
  
    static void CountingEvenOdd(int arr[], 
                              int arr_size) 
    { 
        int even_count = 0;          
        int odd_count = 0;  
        
        //int [] subvector_odd = {};
        Vector<Integer> vector_odd = new Vector<Integer>(); 
        Vector<Integer> vector_even = new Vector<Integer>(); 

              
        // loop to read all the values in 
        // the array 
        for(int i = 0 ; i < arr_size ; i++)  
        { 
            // checking if a number is  
            // completely divisible by 2 
            if ((arr[i] & 1) == 1) 
                odd_count ++ ; 
                vector_odd.addElement(arr[i]);
                
            else                
                even_count ++ ; 
                vector_even.addElement(arr[i]);
        } 
      
        System.out.println( "Number of even"
               + " elements = " + even_count  
               + " Number of odd elements = "
                              + odd_count) ; 
        
        System.out.println(vector_odd); //This vector should look like [1, 3, 5, 7]
        
       
        
    } 
      
    // Driver Code 
    public static void main (String[] args)  
    { 
        int arr[] = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 1, 3, 5, 7}; 
        int n = arr.length; 
        CountingEvenOdd(arr, n); 
    } 
}
```

The output should be:

```
Number of even elements = 5 Number of odd elements = 4
even_vector = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
odd_vector = [1, 3, 5, 7]
```

I'm getting an error in the else statement line when I include the vector.add() method inside the if statement, and I don't understand why...

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modulo operator is %, not & which is bitwise and (see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm ). In addition, array length does not need to be given as parameter and a for loop is not needed. You have everything you need by using the two lines below.

```
Integer[] array = {2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 7};
    Vector<Integer> vectorEven = Arrays.stream(array).filter(i -> i % 2 == 0).collect(Collectors.toCollection(Vector::new));
    Vector<Integer> vectorOdd =Arrays.stream(array).filter(i -> i % 2 == 1).collect(Collectors.toCollection(Vector::new));

    System.out.println(vectorEven);
    System.out.println(vectorOdd.size());
```

Comment: It worked! but I have a problem when I put these lines of code into a method and the I call it from main. 

Throws:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The method subVector(Integer[]) is undefined for the type SplitVectors
 Illegal modifier for parameter subVector; only final is permitted
 Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
 Syntax error on token ")", ; expected

Comment: `public class SplitVectors {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] Vector = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
  System.out.println(subVector(Vector));
  

 public static int[] subVector(Integer[] vector) {
  Vector<Integer> vectorEven = Arrays.stream(vector).filter(i -> i % 2 == 0).collect(Collectors.toCollection(Vector::new));
     Vector<Integer> vectorOdd =Arrays.stream(vector).filter(i -> i % 2 == 1).collect(Collectors.toCollection(Vector::new));
     
     return vectorEven;
     return vectorOdd;
  }
 }//main
}`

this is the code

Comment: It is not possible to return two variables in Java. Whenever you call "return", the code following this statement will not be executed. The second return can never be reached. As a solution.. I would not move the code I provided into a separate method. What do you want to do whit those two vectors?

Comment: I didn't knew that. I need it because it's an exercice I have to do an exercice for my university course. The exercice consist in build two methods inside a class, one tells how many number are odd and even and the other method is to split the vector into odd and even numbers. Personally I would do it in the same method, but......

Comment: If "tells" means you are supposed to print the results, you can still use the code I wrote above. The real "code" will be the same in both methods but in one you print the new vectors, in the other you print the sizes - no return values, just void. However, I can't say if that's the intended answer and I can't say I like this exercise too much, because using the snippet I gave using methods doesn't really help.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your `else` block is not related to any `if` condition (you can omit curly braces if the block contains a single statement, though) .

To fix this, use curly braces to delimit the `if` and `else` blocks :

```
    if ((arr[i] & 1) == 1) {
        odd_count ++ ; 
        vector_odd.addElement(arr[i]);
    }
    else {                
        even_count ++ ; 
        vector_even.addElement(arr[i]);
    }
```

Your current code is equivalent to :

```
if ((arr[i] & 1) == 1) {
    odd_count ++ ;
} 

vector_odd.addElement(arr[i]);

else {                
    even_count ++ ; 
}

vector_even.addElement(arr[i]);
```

As you see, the `else` part can't be related to the `if` part here.

Comment: Adding to this, you do not really need the counts. You can just print the size of the vector_odd and vector_even arrays: System.out.println( "Number of even elements = " + vector_even.size()  + " Number of odd elements = "+ vector_odd.size())